# Running bash script from within python

Tags: python, bash, call

I have a problem with the following code:

**callBash.py:**

```
import subprocess
print "start"
subprocess.call("sleep.sh")
print "end"
```

**sleep.sh:**

```
sleep 10
```

I want the "end" to be printed after 10s. (I know that this is a dumb example, I could simply sleep within python, but this simple sleep.sh file was just as a test)

Comment: I also tried it with "$!bin/bash; sleep 10; "

Comment: It is unclear what problem this questien is trying to ask about, but the question should probably remain because it has accrued a historical grab bag of more or less good guesses as answers. Probably also search for your specific error, and/or read related questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Making sleep.sh executable and adding `shell=True` to the parameter list (as suggested in previous answers) works ok. Depending on the search path, you may also need to add `./` or some other appropriate path.  (Ie, change `"sleep.sh"` to `"./sleep.sh"`.)

The `shell=True` parameter is not needed (under a Posix system like Linux) if the first line of the bash script is a path to a shell; for example, `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Just as additional information `shell=True` is discouraged - [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) because it makes your program vulnerable to shell injections

Answer (score 73):

If `sleep.sh` has the shebang `#!/bin/sh` and it has appropriate file permissions  -- run `chmod u+rx sleep.sh` to make sure and it is in `$PATH` then your code should work as is:

```
import subprocess

rc = subprocess.call("sleep.sh")
```

If the script is not in the PATH then specify the full path to it e.g., if it is in the current working directory:

```
from subprocess import call

rc = call("./sleep.sh")
```

If the script has no shebang then you need to specify `shell=True`:

```
rc = call("./sleep.sh", shell=True)
```

If the script has no executable permissions and you can't change it e.g., by running `os.chmod('sleep.sh', 0o755)` then you could read the script as a text file and pass the string to `subprocess` module instead:

```
with open('sleep.sh', 'rb') as file:
    script = file.read()
rc = call(script, shell=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your work. is there a way to do this without using `import` I want to use your code for homework and we cant use import in the py file

Comment: @c0d3x27 the regular way to run a shell command in Python is to use the `subprocess` module. There are ways to do it without the explicit import in Python but those are dirty hacks reserved for escaping from a sandboxed environment (it is unlikely to be your homework unless you are learning about security in Python).

Comment: Yes, confirm this worked just fine without `shell=True` and in fact using `#!/usr/bin/env zsh` instead since this was macos w zsh.

Answer (score 47):

If someone looking for **calling a script with arguments**

```
import subprocess

val = subprocess.check_call("./script.sh '%s'" % arg, shell=True)
```

Remember to convert the args to string before passing, using str(arg).

This can be used to pass as many arguments as desired:

```
subprocess.check_call("./script.ksh %s %s %s" % (arg1, str(arg2), arg3), shell=True)
```

Comment: I recommend using list as arguments like `subprocess.check_call(["./script.ksh", arg1, arg2, arg3], shell=True)` which seems clearer to me and you do not need to care about formatting.

Answer (score 37):

Actually, you just have to add the `shell=True` argument:

```
subprocess.call("sleep.sh", shell=True)
```

But beware -

> Warning Invoking the system shell with shell=True can be a security hazard if combined with untrusted input. See the warning under Frequently Used Arguments for details.

[source](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module)

Comment: It won't work if `sleep.sh` is not in the `PATH`. And if it *is* in the path and it has the correct shebang then you don't need `shell=True`. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22416147/4279)

Answer (score 16):

Make sure that `sleep.sh` has execution permissions, and run it with `shell=True`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
print "start"
subprocess.call("./sleep.sh", shell=True)
print "end"
```

Comment: so it was the shell=True I missed. Could you explain, why it is not sufficient to set #!bin/bash in the first line of the sh scricpt?

Comment: The error in `#!bin/bash` is a missing `/`.  `#!/bin/bash` works as I note in an answer.

Answer (score 14):

If `chmod` is not working then you can also try:

```bash
import os
os.system('sh script.sh')
# you can also use bash instead of sh
```

Comment: The `os.system` documentation specifically recommends avoiding it in favor of `subprocess` (these days, `subprocess.run()`). If you can't get `subprocess` to work, chances are you'll have trouble with `os.system()` too.

Answer (score 3):

Adding an answer because I was directed here after asking how to run a bash script from python. You receive an error `OSError: [Errno 2] file not found` if your script takes in parameters. Lets say for instance your script took in a sleep time parameter: `subprocess.call("sleep.sh 10")` will not work, you must pass it as an array: `subprocess.call(["sleep.sh", 10])`

Comment: You have to understand [the actual meaning of `shell=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) but yes, usually avoiding it is your best play.