# Getting image as output from php script calling it using python

Tags: php, python

Here I am trying to process an image using a php script textcleaner. I have to run this php script in my other part of python project.I'm confused in getting the output image from php script textcleaner(I get this script from here :

http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/textcleaner/index.php
)

and my code in python for running it is as ..

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen("php textcleaner.php  -g -e none -f 10 -o 5   src.jpg out.jpg", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
script_response = proc.stdout.read()
```

Here `textcleaner.php` is php script file and after that (`-g -e none -f 10 -o 5`)
are the arguments those i want to pass to script(textcleaner) for processing my image(`src.jpg`) and the output image should be `out.jpg`

If any one used this before or know how to get the output in out.jpg as an image please tell me .

I also checked script_response by using print() but it gives me the help menu of textcleaner .

Comment: Your first mistake is that is a bash script and not php code.

Comment: can you please tell me how can i execute it in my python program

Answer (score 0):

This answer [Running bash script from within python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745648/running-bash-script-from-within-python) may point you in the right direction - I do not use Python or bash so can not help further.

```
import subprocess
print "start"
subprocess.call("textcleaner -g -e none -f 10 -o 5 src.jpg out.jpg")
print "end"
```

Do not forget to make textcleaner executable e.g 777 or 755 may work. I would rename textcleaner to textcleaner.sh and use textcleaner.sh in your code. It just reminds you what the file type is.

Comment: Thanks to you for your kind help